# Serenity Screenplay - List of targets

Tags: web-testing, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity screenplay with Java. I have a dropdown list with some options and I want to assert that the options dropdown list has X number of options. I have been using the `Target` class to find elements and assert they contain the correct text etc, but each of my Targets is for a single element. I would like to get a list of Targets and then assert that the list has X elements in it.

I found a class in the Serenity/JS libraries called `TargetElements` ([https://serenity-js.org/modules/protractor/class/src/screenplay/questions/targets/TargetElements.ts~TargetElements.html](https://serenity-js.org/modules/protractor/class/src/screenplay/questions/targets/TargetElements.ts%7ETargetElements.html)) which looks like exactly what I need, but it is not available in the Java version of Serenity.

Here's an example of a typical `Target` that I use:

```java
    public static final Target OPTIONS_LIST_FIELD = Target.the("options field")
                        .located(By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='option_field']"));
```

And I want to do something like this:

```java
    public static final List<Target> OPTIONS_LIST = Target.all("options")
                        .located(By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='option']"));

    assertThat(OPTIONS_LIST.size(), equalTo(6))
```

Comment: I found that I could use `List<WebElementFacade>` in order to achieve what I want. It sort of bridges the gap between Serenity and Selenium, but I'd still much prefer to use `Target` class and somehow get a list of Targets. ([Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89NVV8aiTec) to video explaining `List<WebElement>` and `List<WebElementFacade>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Target` is an abstract class and it's intended usage is to be able to locate and resolve an element on web page. This would give you an instance of either `ByTarget` or `XPathOrCssTarget`.

At the core, the objective should be to get a list of WebElements(`WebElementFacade` in Serenity) on which an action can be performed or can be resolved to assert data.

The following fulfills most of the requirements:

```
List<String> webElementsValues = Target.the("options field").located(By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='option_field']")).resolveForAll(new Actor("Stack")).texts();

List<WebElementFacade> webElements = Target.the("options field").located(By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='option_field']")).resolveForAll(new Actor("Stack"));
```

But if you still want a `List<Target>` elements one can take the following approach which might require some tweak based on your application.

```html
public static List<Target> getListOfTargetElements() {

int sizeOfOptions = Target.the("Parent Element").locatedBy("//..locate your element here").resolveAllFor(new Actor("byteish")).size();
    List<Target> listOfTarget = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeOfOptions;i++){
        listOfTarget.add(Target.the("element:"+i).locatedBy("div/eleme["+i+"]"));
    }

    return listOfTarget;
}
```